# Unable to change hadoop environment variables

Tags: hadoop

I am unable to change the default hadoop environment variables. I was trying to install CDH 5 on a different user when I had a custom hadoop installation on another user.

When I run hadoop version I get

> /usr/bin/hadoop: line 8: /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: No such file or
>   directory

when my $HADOOP_HOME variable is set to

```
hduser@udayPC:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/hadoop
```

I have checked the bashrc it has the paths that I have defined. How can I make sure that the hadoop command runs from `/usr/local/hadoop`?

Comment: Since you are operating in multi user environment, could you please adding the HADOOP variables in .bash_profile file instead of .bashrc file in the current user and try